# Setting up a bare-repository with an existing working directory and pulling from this bare-repository

Tags: git, git-bare

I want to realise the following scenario:

Currently I have an application running on my server for which I yet do not use Git.

I want to setup a bare-repository on my server, so that changes that I push automatically become productive code. Additionally I want to host a project on GitLab hosted by my university for version control and collaborative development as a second remote repository.

My idea would now be the following:

1. Setup the existing directory as the working directory of the bare repository.
2. Pull the files to my local repository.
3. Create a project on GitLab
4. Push those files to the GitLab project

From there on my workflow would be that I would locally work on changes and that I push them to both remote directories.

My questions:

1. Step 2 does not seem to be possible - my search yields that I can't pull the files in the sense that I get the working files directly in my local working directory as I would with a non-bare repository. Is there a simple way to do this?
2. Does this workflow even make sense? I'm new to using Git and open for any suggestions.

Comment: First, you say "I do not yet use Git" and then you say "Setup the existing repository as...". So, which one is it? I'm asking because it is unclear what it means when you say "I work locally and push to *both* remote repositories".

Comment: Sorry for being unspecific here. I meant the existing directory which is already on the server. It should serve as the working directory of the bare-repository which I want to create. "I work locally and push to both remote repositories" means that I want to use git on my laptop and push from there to the server and the gitlab project.

Comment: Bare repositories do not have working directories - that's what makes them bare.